# Pandas get_group excluding group

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to use pandas get_group to get all groups except for the specific group entered.

i.e. instead of doing df.get_group(x) and getting all entries with x, I want to get all entries that don't have x

Thanks

Comment: probably best to use loc... `df.loc[df['col'] != 'group']`

Comment: @rhug123 Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['col'] != 'group']
```

Posted by @rhug123

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).